# invalid conversion from int to *int

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

The code shows an invalid conversion from int to *int how do I fix the problem ... the full detail of error is given below

**ERROR:**

WAP to find the maximum in a dynamic array

In function 'int* search(int*, int)'::

12 invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

**CODE:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int *search (int arr[], int size);

int main()
{
    int ar[5];
    int *loc;  
    cout << "Enter the values in array: \n "; 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cin>> ar[i];

    loc = search(ar,5); 


    for(int i=0;i<10000000000;i++); 
    return 0;   
}


int *search (int arr[], int size)
{
    int *ptr; 
    *ptr = arr; 
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > *ptr)
            ptr = &arr[i];
    }
    return ptr; 
}
```

Comment: How did your code compile with `conio.h`?

Comment: @AlokSave I think it still exists in VS (at least in old versions).

Comment: The error is in the line `*ptr = arr;`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not

```
int *ptr; 
*ptr = arr;
```

It should be

```
int *ptr; 
ptr = arr;
```

Comment: That function has much more problems though.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ or C,

```
int arr[5];
```

the type of arr is int*.

Comment: No, the type of `arr` is `int[5]`. When you pass it to a function (and in many other situations), `arr` is converted to an `int*`, but arrays are very different from pointers.